# An exercise about a function from power set to power set which has the monotonicity property

Tags: functions, solution-verification, set-theory

In "Elements of Set Theory" by Herbert B. Enderton 54p,

> **30.** Assume that $F:\mathscr P A \to\mathscr P A$ and that $F$ has the monotonicity property:
> $$X\subseteq Y\subseteq A \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; F(X) \subseteq F(Y)$$
> Define
> $$B = \bigcap\{X\subseteq A\;|\; F(X) \subseteq X\}\;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\;C = \bigcup\{X\subseteq A\;|\; X \subseteq F(X)\}$$
> (a) Show that $F(B) = B$ and $F(C) = C$.
> (b) Show that if $F(X) = X$, then $B \subseteq X \subseteq C$.

I think by assumption $F(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $F(A) = A$ hold no matter what set A represents. 
Because if $F(\emptyset) \not= \emptyset$, then there exists $X\subseteq A$ such that $X\not=\emptyset$ and $F(X) =\emptyset$. Then $\emptyset\subseteq X$ but $F(\emptyset)\not\subseteq F(X)$. So the monotonicity property doesn't hold, a contradiction. A similar argument shows $F(A) = A$.
Then $\emptyset \in \{X\subseteq A\;|\; F(X) \subseteq X\}$(because $F(\emptyset) \subseteq \emptyset$) so $\bigcap\{X\subseteq A\;|\; F(X) \subseteq X\} = \emptyset = B$.
And $A \in \{X\subseteq A\;|\; X \subseteq F(X)\}$(because $A \subseteq F(A)$) so $\bigcup\{X\subseteq A\;|\; X \subseteq F(X)\} = A = C$. At here (a) and (b) are clear.

If I am right, then in defining B and C, what is the role of $F(X) \subseteq X$ and $X \subseteq F(X)$? And also the condition $F(X) = X$ in (b) seems useless. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have $F(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ unless there are additional assumptions you haven't mentioned (e.g. $F$ being surjective). What if $A=\{1,2\}$ and $F(X):=\{1\}$ for all $X \subseteq A$?

Comment: Oh that's right, I assumed $F$ is surjective although such condition is not in the exercise. I have to reconsider. Thanks.